# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kernel_size'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I'm trying to learn ResNet for Text data. I'm stuck in this error **TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kernel_size'**. code is below. As by previous question post and the suggestion I get This is what I implement according to that.

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Conv1D
from keras.models import Model

CLASSES = 2

def read_pdf():
    df = pd.read_csv("https://data.heatonresearch.com/data/t81-558/jh-simple-dataset.csv", na_values=['NA', '?'])
    return df

def k_fold():
    # Cross-Validate
    no_of_folds = int(input('enter no of K_fold: '))
    kf = KFold(no_of_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)  # Use for KFold classification
    return kf

def epochs_fun():
    EPOCHS = int(input('enter no of epochs: '))
    return EPOCHS
```

now cleaning data and perform K-Fold Cross Validation

```
def prepare_data():
    kf = k_fold()
    df = read_pdf()

    # Generate dummies for job
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['job'], prefix="job")], axis=1)
    df.drop('job', axis=1, inplace=True)
    # Generate dummies for area
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['area'], prefix="area")], axis=1)
    df.drop('area', axis=1, inplace=True)
    # Generate dummies for product
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['product'], prefix="product")], axis=1)
    df.drop('product', axis=1, inplace=True)
    # Missing values for income
    med = df['income'].median()
    df['income'] = df['income'].fillna(med)
    # Standardize ranges
    df['income'] = zscore(df['income'])
    df['aspect'] = zscore(df['aspect'])
    df['save_rate'] = zscore(df['save_rate'])
    df['subscriptions'] = zscore(df['subscriptions'])
    # Convert to numpy - Classification
    x_columns = df.columns.drop('age').drop('id')
    x = df[x_columns].values
    y = df['age'].values
    fold = 0
    for train, test in kf.split(x):
        fold += 1
        print(f"Fold #{fold}")
        x_train = x[train]
        y_train = y[train]
        x_test = x[test]
        y_test = y[test]
        print(x_train)
        print(y_train)
        print(x_test)
        print(y_test)
        return [x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,x]
```

Identity Block:

```
def identity_block(X, filters):

    # Retrieve Filters
    F1 = filters

    # Save the input value. We'll need this later to add back to the main path.
    X_shortcut = X

    # First component of main path
    X = Conv1D(filters = F1)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Second component of main path
    X = Conv1D(filters = F1, kernel_size = 3)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Third component of main path
    X = Conv1D()(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    # Final step: Add shortcut value to main path, and pass it through a RELU activation
    X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    return X
```

convolutional_block:

```
def convolutional_block(X, filters):
    # Retrieve Filters
    F1 = filters
    ##### MAIN PATH #####
    # First component of main path
    X = Conv1D(F1)(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Second component of main path
    X = Conv1D(filters=F1, kernel_size=(3))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Third component of main path
    X = Conv1D(filters=F1, kernel_size=(3))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)

    ##### SHORTCUT PATH ####
    X_shortcut = BatchNormalization()

    # Final step: Add shortcut value to main path, and pass it through a RELU activation
    X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    return X
```

ResNet Block:

```
def ResNet50(input_shape, classes=2):
    # Define the input as a tensor with shape input_shape
    X_input = Input(input_shape)

    # Zero-Padding
   # X = ZeroPadding2D()(X_input)

    # Stage 1
    X = Conv1D(64)(X_input)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Stage 2
    X = convolutional_block(X)
    X = identity_block(X)

    # Stage 3
    X = convolutional_block(X)
    X = identity_block(X)

    # output layer
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(X)

    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X, name='ResNet50')

    return model
```

Train the model:

```
def model_check():
    data = prepare_data()
    X_train = data[0]
    Y_train = data[1]
    x = data[4]
    epochs = epochs_fun()
    model = ResNet50(input_shape = x.shape[1], classes = CLASSES)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = epochs, batch_size = 64)

model_check()
```

NOTE::: error is in line

```
#Stage 1 
X = Conv1D(64)(X_input) # in ResNet50 function
```

so if I change this line to

```
X = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(3))(X)
```

then the error change to

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 53)
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error? Did you look at the documentation for the class that is raising the error?

Comment: @JohnColeman     
# Stage 1
`X = Conv1D(64)(X_input)`
in ResNet50 function

Comment: Compare your own code: X = Conv1D(filters = F1)(X) vs X = Conv1D(filters=F1, kernel_size=(3))(X), see what is missing?

Comment: `X = Conv1D()(X)` will also raise an error. You seem to be treating its arguments as optional, but the error message tells you that they are not.

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried it with that then it through this erro:: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 53)`

Comment: I have previously said that you want a ResNet with only Dense layers, not with convolutional layers, that is why you get this error. You cannot just ignore advice and expect code to work.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy with that the error is `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=0. Full shape received: ()`

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried that too. so the above error occure. this error occure when I remove the kernal_size

Comment: Why is you data now zero dimensional?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy if i add kernal_size then the error is:: `TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'kernel_size')`

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that's I don't understand why the dimensions change

Comment: You are just trying random things without really understanding why you are doing it, with this people are much less likely to help you. You really need to understand what is happening first, else helping you is not useful to you.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried to print the shape passing the same shape up there But I don't understand whats wrong. and yes I'm trying random things if one thing fail and tired to fix so I move to other one

Answer (score 0):

"**TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument**" 
occurs when we forget to provide a required argument when instantiating a class.

`To solve the error` :
specify the argument when instantiating the class or set a default value for the argument

Comment: Bro I know this but here I don't know what I missed.